# Segmentation fault when implementing insertion sort

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, insertion-sort

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a[6] = {5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3}; // create an array of size 6
    int j, key = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        key = a[i];
        j = i - 1;
        while ((j >= 0) && (a[j] > key)) {
            a[j + 1] = a[j];
            j -= 1;
        }
        a[j + 1] = key;
    }
    for (int l = 0; l < 6; l++) { 
        cout << a[l];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to test my insertion sort code using an array
the code complies but when I try to execute the a.out file,
it gives me "Segmentation Fault",
I look up what segmentation fault is, it's basically an error that we are trying to access the forbidden memory location, however, **I'm wondering where exactly is the error in my code.** Also, if i get rid of the

```
for (int l = 0; l < 6; l++) { 
    cout << a[l];
}
```

no error is found.

Comment: `j` is not initialized. This may not be the cause of your problem, but it's still bad practice.

Comment: it doesn't work still, what i mean is that when i try to print out the result, the error occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable `j` is not initialized and so may be anything when you first access `a[j]`. That causes the segmentation fault. (`int j,key =0;` only sets `key` to `0` but not `j`.)

Always compile your code with `-Wall`, this would have told you about the use of the uninitialized variable. (Correction: My gcc 4.7 doesn't catch it. How lame.)

(The reason why the error goes away when you remove the printing is that you have compiler optimizations turned on: The compiler then notices that you never do anything practical with the computed values and arrays and just throws everything into the bin and gives you an empty program.)

Comment: I have explained this. First paragraph, in the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

sorting is one of the algorithms in the stl. you should really be using std::sort like

```
std::sort( a, a+6 );
```

PS: j is initialized before use in the line

```
j = i - 1;
```

so that is not the cause of the crash.

Comment: I too don't understand why `j` is said not to be initialized, the `j = i - 1;` clearly does so, as you said.